# Created a simple mute button for my Android game but it crashes the app?

Tags: android, crash, mute

I'm creating a game for Android, so I decided to create a mute button which would pause the music. I added the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

            if (inBounds(event, 4, 3, 80, 35)) {
                 if (AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true) {
                     AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.0f,0.0f);
                 }

            }

        }
    }
```

So when you touch anywhere from 4, 3, 80, 35 (the mute button) it would check if the musis is playing and if it is it would set the volume to 0.0f.
I've also tried with:

```
AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer.pause();
```

but it didn't work either.

When I erase this part of this code, it all works perfectly, but when I place them again, the menu loads but the moment you touch anywhere (even the Play button, or an empty space) it stops and then crashes.

EDIT: Here's the LogCat,

```
06-09 09:59:38.565: I/Process(24310): Sending signal. PID: 24310 SIG: 9
06-09 09:59:43.075: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 10% free 12147K/13443K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
06-09 09:59:43.080: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.647MB for 768016-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.095: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 12896K/14215K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-09 09:59:43.140: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 10% free 12903K/14215K, paused 15ms+12ms, total 45ms
06-09 09:59:43.145: V/SoundPoolThread(26060): beginThread
06-09 09:59:43.145: V/SoundPoolThread(26060): run
06-09 09:59:43.145: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): native_setup
06-09 09:59:43.145: V/MediaPlayer(26060): constructor
06-09 09:59:43.150: V/MediaPlayer(26060): setListener
06-09 09:59:43.150: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): setDataSourceFD: fd 43
06-09 09:59:43.150: V/MediaPlayer(26060): setDataSource(43, 241934, 1635707)
06-09 09:59:43.160: V/MediaPlayer(26060): setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-09 09:59:43.160: V/MediaPlayer(26060): prepare
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): New video size 0 x 0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): callback application
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): back from callback
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): prepared
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): signal application thread
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): callback application
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): prepare complete - status=0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): back from callback
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): setLooping: 1
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): MediaPlayer::setLooping
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): setVolume: left 0.850000  right 0.850000
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.850000, 0.850000)
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): isPlaying: 0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): isPlaying: 0
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): start
06-09 09:59:43.165: V/MediaPlayer(26060): start
06-09 09:59:43.180: V/MediaPlayer(26060): isPlaying: 1
06-09 09:59:43.180: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): isPlaying: 1
06-09 09:59:43.185: I/MediaPlayer(26060): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
06-09 09:59:43.230: D/libEGL(26060): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-09 09:59:43.235: D/libEGL(26060): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-09 09:59:43.235: D/libEGL(26060): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-09 09:59:43.240: D/(26060): Device driver API match
06-09 09:59:43.240: D/(26060): Device driver API version: 10
06-09 09:59:43.240: D/(26060): User space API version: 10 
06-09 09:59:43.240: D/(26060): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
06-09 09:59:43.270: D/OpenGLRenderer(26060): Enabling debug mode 0
06-09 09:59:43.295: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 9% free 12942K/14215K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
06-09 09:59:43.295: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.423MB for 768016-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.315: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 13691K/14983K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 23ms
06-09 09:59:43.315: D/dalvikvm(26060): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
06-09 09:59:43.350: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 9% free 13695K/14983K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
06-09 09:59:43.350: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.892MB for 1536016-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.375: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 15195K/16519K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 25ms
06-09 09:59:43.375: D/dalvikvm(26060): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
06-09 09:59:43.430: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 15196K/16519K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
06-09 09:59:43.435: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.358MB for 1536016-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.465: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 16696K/18055K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
06-09 09:59:43.465: D/dalvikvm(26060): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
06-09 09:59:43.510: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 16696K/18055K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
06-09 09:59:43.520: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.313MB for 4147216-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.540: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 20746K/22151K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 23ms
06-09 09:59:43.730: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1503K, 12% free 21044K/23687K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
06-09 09:59:43.810: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1501K, 12% free 21042K/23687K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
06-09 09:59:43.815: I/dalvikvm-heap(26060): Grow heap (frag case) to 25.557MB for 4147216-byte allocation
06-09 09:59:43.845: D/dalvikvm(26060): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 25092K/27783K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 26ms
06-09 09:59:46.130: V/MediaPlayer(26060): isPlaying: 1
06-09 09:59:46.130: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): isPlaying: 1
06-09 09:59:46.130: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(26060): pause
06-09 09:59:46.130: V/MediaPlayer(26060): pause
06-09 09:59:47.450: W/dalvikvm(26060): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410ba2a0)
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4402
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060):    at com.kilobolt.robotgame.MainMenuScreen.update(MainMenuScreen.java:35)
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060):    at com.kilobolt.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:47)
06-09 09:59:47.455: E/AndroidRuntime(26060):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I did initialize mediaPlayer, here's the AndroidMusic class:

```
package com.kilobolt.framework.implementation;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;

import com.kilobolt.framework.Music;

public class AndroidMusic implements Music, OnCompletionListener, OnSeekCompleteListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean isPrepared = false;

    public AndroidMusic(AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    assetDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                    assetDescriptor.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            isPrepared = true;
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

         if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
               this.mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
        this.mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mediaPlayer.isLooping();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStopped() {
        return !isPrepared;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.pause();
    }



    @Override
    public void play() {
        if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            return;

        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (!isPrepared)
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void muteSound() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
         if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
        this.mediaPlayer.stop();

       synchronized (this) {
           isPrepared = false;
        }}
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        synchronized (this) {
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void seekBegin() {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         synchronized (this) {
               isPrepared = true;
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer player) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer player, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void CurrVolume(float volume) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

HalR, I tried your code and that made the "mute" button pause the music and not crash the app, but it still crashes when I press the "play" button.

Comment: Please give the LogCat. It helps to know the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to know, with partial code.  But given what you've shown, and how "boiler plate" it looks, I would suspect that you haven't initialized your mediaPlayer.

You should surround your code with a check to see if the mediaPlayer exists. Like this:

```
if (AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

            if (inBounds(event, 4, 3, 80, 35)) {
                 if (AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true) {
                     AndroidMusic.mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.0f,0.0f);
                 }

            }

        }
    }
}
```